# Ruby Grape: How to send array of hashes as param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, swagger, ruby-grape

I sends an array of hashes.

```
[{question_id: 1_id, answer:1_String},{question_id: 2_id, answer:2_String}]
```

and I used this code in my API file:

```
requires :profile_setting, type: Array[Hash], desc: "[{question_id: 1_id, answer: '1_String'},{question_id: 2_id, answer: '2_String'}]"
```

[image]

params: `[{question_id: 1_id, answer:1_String},{question_id: 2_id, answer:2_String}]`

response:

```
{
  "error": "profile_setting is invalid"
}
```

how to send a Array of multiple hashes.

Comment: Swagger 2.0 does not support JSON objects/arrays in formData params (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`). You'll probably need to change the endpoint to accept `application/json` instead.

Comment: I believe your issue may actually be the documentation and that the expectation is `[{question_id: 1, answer:"1"},{question_id: 2, answer:"2"}]` and the trailing `_*` are the expected data type and not part of the actual expectation for formatting

Comment: @Helen yeah you are right. when i use Postman it works.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON misses quotes around keys and values.

Should be

```
[{
"question_id": "1 _id",
"answer": "1 _String"
},
{
"question_id": "2 _id",
"answer": "2 _String"
}]
```

Comment: did not work still the same error {"error": "profile_setting is invalid"}